# Load js/jq inside tinybox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Tinybox to load some content and i need to load js files from inside the tinybox.

I can load a new tinybox inside from the tinybox.

I can't load anything else related to js.

I have read about people suggesting using .on() - I though don't see documentation that makes my mind understand how this should work.

```
            <p onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>',width:650,height:550})">Read More</p>
```

I tried loading with iframe since i did see someone else from this site told he made a solution that way.. His solution though made no sense to me.. i tried the below for iframe.

The iframe loads and i can't find solutions on how to load js into this either.

```
<p onclick="TINY.box.show({iframe:'product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>',boxid:'frameless',width:650,height:550,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40,closejs:function(){closeJS()}})" >Read More</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

**IN ADDITION FOR THE SOLUTION FINDING..

Index.php

```
    ..<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.rateit.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/yepnope.1.5.4.min.js"></script>..    

 <div class="rateit">This is a working star rating</div>

$Post(search.php)..
```

**
Search.php (same window(index.php) - different div)

```
Grid list While.. <div class="rateid">STAR RATING ONLY WORKING WHEN script is included</div> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.rateit.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/yepnope.1.5.4.min.js"></script>

        <p onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>',width:650,height:550})">Read More</p>

    <script>
        yepnope.injectJs("js/jquery.rateit.js", function () 
        {
        alert('File Loaded');
        }, {
        charset: "utf-8"
        }, 5000);
        </script>
```

**
Product.php (LOADING CONTENTS)

```
<div class="rateid">THIS IS NOT WORKING</div>    <p onclick="TINY.box.show({url:'product.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>',width:650,height:550})">THIS IS WORKING!</p>
```

Comment: just show html which includes <script> tag

Comment: you can also use great tool http://yepnopejs.com/
and its InjectJs feature

Comment: MySqlError.. Can you please use a few more words on what i should do in relation to the first post.

Comment: which version of tinybox you're using ?

Comment: I just downloaded the Tinybox2 and the files are equal, so have been using Tinybox2

Answer (score 0):

you're loading product.php?id=? 
include `<script src="yourjavascriptfilehere" ></script>` into response of product.php?id=

if that doesn't work due specification of tinybox then use this http://yepnopejs.com/ library
and include this code into your product.php?id= response

```
<script>
yepnope.injectJs("file.js", function () 
{
  alert('file loaded');
}, {
  charset: "utf-8"
}, 5000);
</script>
```

doing iframes should not be necessary

Comment: Could you please explain the first sentence.

Comment: For the yep.. Is this right ?    <script>
   yepnope.injectJs("js/jquery.rateit.js", function () 
   {
   alert('product.php');
   }, {
   charset: "utf-8"
   }, 5000);
   </script>

Comment: I can't seem to get the yepnope to work.. The examples on their website just isn't "doing" it for me.

Comment: have you downloaded and included library ?

Comment: I will update the above code, since it is too complex to input here.